# Comparing 2 dictionary values and adding max value to 3rd dictionary

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and having an issue comparing the Value in keys of 2 dictionaries and printing to a third.

Two dictionaries print a players' stats as follows.

```
player_stats1 = {'Hits':'230', 'AVG': '.304', 'HR':'235', 'SB':'10', 'RBI':'101' }
player_stats2 = {'Hits':'163', 'AVG': '.265', 'HR':'567', 'SB':'45', 'RBI':'65'}
```

I would like to take the highest value from each key and add them to a blank dictionary (`player_statswin`).

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
player_stats1 = {'Hits':'230', 'AVG': '.304', 'HR':'235', 'SB':'10', 'RBI':'101' }
player_stats2 = {'Hits':'163', 'AVG': '.265', 'HR':'567', 'SB':'45', 'RBI':'65'}

player_statswin = {k:max(float(v),float(player_stats2[k])) for k,v in player_stats1.items()}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If both dictionaries always have exactly the same keys (no missing keys) then you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
player_stats1 = {'Hits':'230', 'AVG': '0.304', 'HR':'235', 'SB':'10', 'RBI':'101' }
player_stats2 = {'Hits':'163', 'AVG': '0.265', 'HR':'567', 'SB':'45', 'RBI':'65'}

player_statswin = { k:max(map(float,(v1,player_stats2[k]))) for k,v1 in player_stats1.items() }

print(player_statswin)
# {'Hits': 230.0, 'AVG': 0.304, 'HR': 567.0, 'SB': 45.0, 'RBI': 101.0}
```

If there can be different/missing keys, then you will need to merge them:

```
player_statswin = dict(sorted((*player_stats1.items(),*player_stats2.items()),key=lambda kv:float(kv[1])))

print(player_statswin)
# {'AVG': '0.304', 'SB': '45', 'RBI': '101', 'Hits': '230', 'HR': '567'}
```

*BTW, you should store your values as int/floats instead of strings. This would reduce the number of float conversions all over your code*

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to extract keys from dictionnary like :

```py
dict.keys()
```

Then use the max method to extract the max of the 2 values and put this value into the new dictionnary :

```py
max(value, value)
```